# Voltage of 3 V batteries

Tags: voltage, batteries, low-battery

I ordered 3 V CR2 batteries. Actually they are 2.92 V and 2.93 V.

Should I consider them faulty, or is this difference from the nominal voltage acceptable?

Comment: Or consider your voltmeter uncalibrated?

Comment: It depends how you measure them. How do you measure them?

Comment: I measure them with a battery tester.

Comment: OK. How does the battery tester test them?

Comment: And... What were your results?

Comment: @MicroservicesOnDDD the results are in my question.

Comment: @Justme the battery tester measures the voltage and displays it.  What else can it do?

Comment: @user31264 - As explained in the comment under my answer, without a load, measuring the voltage of the battery is useless. Even a dead CR2032 will show a high voltage if you don't put a load across it. This is a confusing non-intuitive behavior of batteries. The slow pumping of the chemical reaction artificially keeps the voltage high when there's no current flowing (to speak of).

Comment: @user31264 That's not how battery testers usually work. They usually put a load on the battery, likely a resistor, before measuring and displaying voltage. If the current is low, the battery reads a higher voltage than if the current is high. If you don't know how the tester measures the battery, you can't really say if the voltage reading you get means good or bad or something in between.

Comment: @user31264 - You said, "the results are in my question", but that's not true without a real test, and we don't know if you used a real test or not. A real test requires a load (a resistor). The continuous draw graph on the datasheet used 15K as a load, so that's the maximum resistance across the battery that I would use to read the voltage.

Comment: @user31264 - I'm sorry that testing a battery is so complicated, but that's just the way it is. Please see my updated answer with a picture of how to test. And don't forget to upvote a worthy answer, and put the green check-mark next to the answer that helped you the most. Thank you. We work hard for the points.

Comment: @user31264 You could [edit] your question to include the make and model of battery tester that you used. And if you tested them at an ambient temperature more than a few degrees away from 20°C, that could be useful for us to know too. Oh, and to show how much detail we'd like, there should have been a date on the batteries' packaging to indicate the latest date they should be installed.

Answer (score 5):

They are likely fine.  Batteries are not constant voltage sources.  While the the chemical reactions that liberate their stored energy "create" the same voltage as they proceed, reaction products build up and increase the internal resistance which has the effect of lowering the voltage at their terminals.  Take a look at this discharge curve for a Duracell 2032 battery with different resistance loads attached to it.  You can see that they all start out at somewhere above 3V, rapidly drop to somewhat below 3V, and then gradually decline until the battery is "dead" and the voltage starts to drop rapidly.  Battery powered circuits are (or should be) designed to deal with these changes in voltage.  [image: Image from https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Duracell/CR2032.pdf]
Image source: https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Duracell/CR2032.pdf

Answer (score 3):

Usually, 3-volt batteries come higher than 3 volts. Get a battery tester and see what it says. Harbor Freight's cheapest multimeter (sometimes given away free, $5 last I checked) has a battery tester built in. Internally, they use a 360 ohm resistor across the battery and measure the current. A healthy 3-volt battery should pull 8.33 mA according to this scheme.  If they draw only 6mA, I would ask for a refund.

Looking at this graph from an [Energizer CR2032 datasheet](https://data.energizer.com/pdfs/cr2032.pdf):

[image]

You should see highlighted in orange the pulsed test current-vs-voltage curve, and that 400 ohms was used for the test (at 2 seconds pulse, 12 times per day). If you test with the suggested 360 ohms, it should be an acceptable test. The cutoff voltage for this CR2032 is 2-volts, which corresponds to a draw of 5.55mA through 360 ohms.

You can also measure the voltage of the CR2032 while you're testing it, and see how low its voltage drops. The manufacturer Energizer considers their CR2032 dead at 2 volts.

Here is what your test should look like:

[image]

Internally, a true battery tester does this, so you won't see the resistor. But you can do the above with a regular resistor and get the results you seek -- a true and correct answer! Just set the meter to measure volts while the resistor is across the battery as shown.

For example: The voltage measured determines the current flowing in the resistor. V=IR, so I=V/R = (voltage shown on multimeter)/(measured resistance of resistor). Let's say the voltage shows as 2.5V and the resistance you used is 500, then 2.5/500 = 0.005 = 5mA. Since the manufacturer has determined that 2V is the cut-off, and 3V is nominal, and 2.5 is right between them, you probably have less than half the life of your battery left with the numbers of this example.

---

[Here is a link to the Harbor Freight multimeter](https://www.harborfreight.com/electrical/electrician-s-tools/multimeters-testers/7-function-digital-multimeter-59434.html) that I mentioned, and here's a picture with the switch setting highlighted:

[image]

Comment: "Get a battery tester and see what it says" - did you read the question?  I got a battery tester and saw what it says.  And please PLEASE don't ask me "what does it say?", because the answer is in my question.

Comment: @user31264 - No, it is not apparent. Most people test batteries with a voltage meter, which does not test the battery at all. Unless you put a load across the battery, the open-circuit voltage of the battery is most misleading. The battery could be almost completely dead and register 2.92 volts! So no, our questions are not unreasonable at all. Are you testing the batteries with a load across them, is the real question.

Comment: @user31264 where did you say that you got a battery tester? I read your question and thought that you measured it with a multimeter.